# Multiple returns or return a tuple in vyper?

Tags: vyper

I have a contract:

```py
interface IAggregatorV3:
    def getRoundData(uint80) -> [uint80, int256, uint256, uint256, uint80]: view
```

And the contract in solidity returns a tuple of multiple types. How do I return many types in vyper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get mutiple return values like so:

```py
def getRoundData(_roundId: uint80) -> (uint80, int256, uint256, uint256, uint80): view
```